# Dynamic access of environment variables in NextJS not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, create-react-app

I cannot access environment variables dynamically in NextJS. In `.env.local` I have:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST=test
```

In `_app.tsx` I have:

```
const test = "NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST";
console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST); // = 'test'
console.log(process.env[test]); // = undefined
```

I tried the same thing in Create React APP:

```
# .env
const test = 'REACT_APP_TEST'
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_TEST) // = 'test'
console.log(process.env[test]) // = 'test'
```

Does anybody know why NextJS doesn't allow this and how to override it? I'm aware `next.config.js` is a thing, but I'd like to use `.env`.

Comment: @brc-dd it is, check your console, it's logging undefined

Comment: I need the values in the browser, that was the problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables):

> **Note:** In order to keep server-only secrets safe, Next.js replaces `process.env.*` with the correct values at build time. This means that `process.env` is not a standard JavaScript object.

Hence what you are trying to do is only possible in development mode, that too in the server side code.

You can manually create an object that maps exposed environment constants and use it instead of `process.env` if you truly want to use dynamic values.

[Here is an example:](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-sutherland-7yisp)

```js
// utils/config.js

export default {
  TEST: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TEST
};
```

```js
// pages/index.js

import config from "../utils/config";

const test = "TEST";
console.log(config[test]);

const IndexPage = () => <div>Hello World</div>;
export default IndexPage;
```

Comment: Cheers, it's a shame it's like this. Create React App achieves the same level of security (only lets prefixed env variables through) without breaking the object

Comment: @bdmason You can try create an object yourself mapping all public environments and use it instead of `process.env`.

Comment: @bcr-dd I saw that was a way to do config, but I wanted it to be gitignored. There did appear to be a way of setting it per environment too, for my project that may be the best solution anyway as client env vars are never secret, and it saves us all passing around env var files. Thanks for the help