# Access environment variables from client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm making a lot of API calls from within my components using `fetch`. Everytime I had to write this logic to determine which environment I'm in So, I created a Utils class which returns the correct base url:

```
export default class Utils {
  static get baseUrl() {
    const inDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
    const { NEXT_PUBLIC_DEV_URL, NEXT_PUBLIC_PROD_URL } = process.env;
    return inDev ? NEXT_PUBLIC_DEV_URL : NEXT_PUBLIC_PROD_URL;
  }
}
```

But now I'm getting this error when my component loads:

```
ReferenceError: process is not defined
```

I looked around and found that I need to mark my variables as NEXT_PUBLIC so I did but the problem still persists. What's the ideal way to handle this?

Comment: Are you trying to do that from code in the *browser*?

Comment: Yes, but I suppose `next.js` replaces env variables with actual values using webpack right?

Comment: The `process` object is not available in the browser; it does not make sense. You'll have to make an ajax call from client to server, or else ensure that your server provides that contextual information as part of your standard page templates.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Dynamic access of environment variables in NextJS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314905/dynamic-access-of-environment-variables-in-nextjs-not-working)? _"Next.js replaces `process.env.*` with the correct values at build time. This means that `process.env` is not a standard JavaScript object."_ - meaning you can't destructure `process.env` on the client-side, you have to use `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEV_URL` as is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expose ENV variables to the client you can use [publicRuntimeConfig](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration) inside your NextJS configuration (`next.config.js`). Here is how you could do it:

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
  myEnvVar: process.env.MY_ENV_VAR
}
```

And then in the file you would like to use your ENV variable:

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();

const envVar = publicRuntimeConfig.myEnvVar // store in it a 'const' or do whatever you want with it,;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class can actually look like this :-

```js
export default class Utils {
  static get baseUrl() {
    return process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL;
  }
}
```

The `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix should work well for inlining the values which are replaced at build time and sent to the browser as per [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser).

In your **.env.development** (or whatever your dev environment file is called) file, you can have `NEXT_PUBLIC_URL` pointing to `http://localhost:8000` and in your production you will probably have production env variables setup using a GUI (like in Netlify or Vercel), so there `NEXT_PUBLIC_URL` can be `https://blablasite.com`.

Either way, `NEXT_PUBLIC` prefix will ensure that at build time those values are picked up and inlined before sending the same to browser.