# NextJS next/image Failed to parse src with Strapi 4 and Graphql

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, strapi

I'm not able to load the images with the next/image handler from the strapi cms.

the images are working perfectly with the normal  tag but not with the next/image handler

My Setup
.env:

```
STRAPI_GRAPHQL_API=http://localhost:1337/graphql
API_URL=http://localhost:1337
IMAGES_DOMAIN=localhost
```

next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

  images: {
    domains: [process.env.IMAGES_DOMAIN],
    path: '/_next/image', 
    loader: 'default',
  },
}
```

Gallery component:

```
import Image from 'next/image'


const Intro = ({imageGallery}) => {
    const { API_URL } = process.env
    return (
        <div>
            {imageGallery.Images.data.map(image => {
                const src = API_URL + image.attributes.url
                return (
                    <div key={image.id}>
                       <Image src={src} width={200} height={200} />
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Intro;
```

Error Message:

1 of 6 unhandled errors

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Failed to parse src "undefined/uploads/Zucker_Nicolas_Gysin_DD_6_237_7b0eee1060.jpeg" on `next/image`, if using relative image it must start with a leading slash "/" or be an absolute URL (http:// or https://)

console.log(src) has a valid url with http://localhost:133/uploadas…

Comment: The problem was, you have to define the env in the next.config.js

`env:{API_URL:process.env.API_URL`

Comment: To expose and access an environment variable to the client you have to prefix it with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. Also, in Next.js, you can't destructure `process.env` variables that way. See [Dynamic access of environment variables in NextJS not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68314905/dynamic-access-of-environment-variables-in-nextjs-not-working).

Answer (score 1):

given this question is only 24 days old atm, I presume you use the latest Next.js version (version 9.4 or up).

If that is the case, you should **not** be defining your environment variables in your `next.config.js` file. Instead, you should be using your `.env.local`/ `.env` file to load and store your env constants.

Additionally you can expose these to the browser directly through starting your declarations with `NEXT_PUBLIC_YOUR_VARIABLE`.

So technically, your `.env` should be:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_GRAPHQL_API=http://localhost:1337/graphql
NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:1337
NEXT_PUBLIC_IMAGES_DOMAIN=localhost
```